# How to convert current date format(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to (YYMMDD) format in freemarker language

Tags: freemarker, smooks

I have used code `${.now?iso("UTC")}` to get the current date and time stamp inside the freemarker templates, but I would like to convert the current date format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to (YYMMDD) format. Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment (2.3.28) `?string` doesn't support forcing UTC. So if the `time_zone` FreeMarker configuration setting is not UTC, you can do this:

```
<#setting time_zone="UTC">
${.now?string('yyyyMMdd')}
```

However, then the further dates will also use UTC. If that's a problem then either you use a custom date format (which is a date format implemented in custom Java code, so it can do anything; see: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html#pgui_config_custom_formats_ex_cust_algo_date), or use this hack:

```
${.now?date?iso('UTC')?replace('-', '')}
```